# ExecuteNonQuery() does not return the affected rows in C# and SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and Visual Studio 2010. The issue happen when using `ExecuteNonQuery()` command. In most cases, it returns the real number of rows affected, but when I tried to delete a group of records, it returns 0.

When I opened the table in SQL Server Management Studio, I see 33 records were deleted.

This is my code:

```
sqlQuery = "delete from  priv_  where user_id=" + txt_id.Text;
cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
MessageBox.Show("rows affected = " + cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());
```

The message box show

```
rows affected = 0
```

When I use the same query in SQL Server Management Studio, it shows

```
33 rows affected
```

I have change the `ONCOUNT` to off, but nothing change.

Comment: How do you know you are using the same statement? Did you copy it from the debugger from this variable: `sqlQuery`

Comment: Use SQL Profiler and trace the call and make sure the statement indeed is executed.  Also take the ExecuteNonQuery outside of the MessageBox statement and assign it a variable of int and convert that int properly toString(), instead of implicit "addition operation" on 2 different types.

Comment: I have assign the statement a variable , but it does not change anything.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this problem for few weeks.I had a problem with the login rights that I was using for the database. I was able to run queries but not from my application and it does not throw any error. So I added the 'owner' rights to the login in SQL Server 2014 under

> My_server->Security->logins->My_login->Properties->User
>   Mappings->My_database->Select appropriate rights